# Custom name & justification, single line spread and "within chapter" numbering of figure captions

Tags: numbering, captions, line-spacing

I now know how to add images with captions but still need help how to tweak the captions.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{01.jpg}
\caption*{\textbf{Bild 2.1:} Curtiss XP-23 mit einem Turbo-Superlader, 1923. Arbeitsergebnis von Sanford Moss, der US-Armee und der GE Company.}    
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

And my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2.0cm}{2cm}
\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
```

Here is my code, I need to remove the linespacing of the caption and to left-align it and to remove *Abbildung 1* because now I'm in the second chapter and it's the first image so *Bild 2.1* or can you tell me how to connect the image to the chapter?

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `caption*`? Use `caption`. Don't user `center`environment inside `figure`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel that was just an attempt to remove the automatic labeling just as in chapters and sections but it didn't work =)

Comment: Can you provide a complete mwe with `documentclass` and `end{document}`. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Ok Iadded my main code. I need to left-align the caption to remove the automatic labeling _Abbildung 1:_ and to remove the linespacing for the caption.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel ok everything works now =) I forgot to use `\usepackage{caption}`. But still want to know how to remove the line spacing.

Comment: Ok. However please note: [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel hmm I tried both didn't see any changes.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The line spacing comes from `\linespacing{1.8}`. If you use package `setspace` it resets the line spacing to single spacing for footnotes and in floats:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2.0cm}{2cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}% consider package `parskip' 

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}
\usepackage[bf]{caption}
\addto\captionsngerman{%
  \renewcommand*{\figurename}{Bild}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{01.jpg}
\caption{Curtiss XP-23 mit einem Turbo-Superlader, 1923.
Arbeitsergebnis von Sanford Moss, der US-Armee und der GE Company.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Caption]

Remarks:

- I have changed the `babel` language to `ngerman` (new spelling). Language `german` is for old texts of the previous century.
- `\centering` instead of environment `center` avoids additional vertical space.
- Because of package `babel` the redefinition of `\figurename` should be done in `\captions<language>`.

Answer (score 2):

- Do not use `\linespread` because it modifies the line spread everywhere in the document, including footnotes and captions. This is rarely what you want. Instead, use the `\setstretch` command from the `setspace` package, which will affect the line spread of the main text.
- You can customise the appearance of captions with the `\captionsetup` command from the `caption` package; see my code below. No need to resort to `\caption*` and typeset the caption name and number manually, then; simply use `\caption`.
- Refrain from using a `center` environment in a `figure` environment; see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables?lq=1) for more details about why you should prefer the `\centering` declaration, in that case.
- By default, in the `report` class, figures will be numbered within chapters, as desired.
- There was a mistake in one argument of the `\titleformat` command you use to format chapter headings; see my correction below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\titleformat{\section}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}  % <--- I substituted
                                                            % "\thechapter" for
                                                            % the "\thesection", here
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{2.0cm}{2cm}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{%
    name=Bild,%
    labelfont=bf,%
    justification=raggedright%
}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.8}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\setcounter{chapter}{1}     % just to pretend there was a first 
                            % chapter before the one entitled "foo"
\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[2]

\section{My first section}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{01.jpg}
\caption{Curtiss XP-23 mit einem Turbo-Superlader,
    1923. Arbeitsergebnis von Sanford Moss, der US-Armee und der GE Company.}    
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{01.jpg}
\caption{Some other picture}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note: don't forget to remove the `demo` option of the `graphicx` package, or you will get black rectangles in place of your external images.